# can not prepare primary database for standby database creation (for RMAN)

Tags: backup, oracle11g, rman

```
 i was trying to prepare a primary database for standby database creation. while executing set_log_params.sql, we struck with an error "ORA-32017 failure in updating SPFILE" and "ORA-00439 feature not enabled: managed standby".
```

from the detailed error message, it has been seen that the error when setting "log_archive_dest_2" parameter.

we are using oracle 11g standard edition with RHEL 5

It will be appreciable if you could tell me if there will be an easy way to setup a backup database server.

thanks and regards

Jayalaxmi

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain that the creation of standby databases is a feature of Enterprise Edition only.

Answer (score 0):

RMAN has this capability, if you are using poor man's oracle like we are, you can take care of the log shipping and log apply with shell scripts and cron (unix) or batch files and scheduler (windows) we do it every 30 minutes....